# Creating Thumbnails from json

Tags: json, twitter-bootstrap, thumbnails

I have a json object of locations like this:

```
    {"locations":[{"name":"fool1","lat":"41.6504","long":"-0.879137","img":"http://link1.com}, 
                  {"name":"fool2","lat":"41.6049","long":"-0.899137","img":"http://link2.com}]}
```

How could I generate custom bootstrap thumbnails (i.e. with name and pics) dynamically?

I know how to access the json, for example I show the location on google map using javascipt.

So I would now populate dynamically thumbnails with the json.

My code is:

```
<script>

$(function() {
   $.getJSON('mappa/bares.json', function(data) {
       $.each(data.locations, function(i, f) {
           $('#main-content').
              append("<div class="thumbnail">"+
                     "<img src="f.img">" + 
                     "<div class="f.nombre">"+
                     "<h3>" +f.nombre+"</h3>"+
                     "</div>"+
                     "</div>"                                     
                    );
           });

       });

});
</script>


<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
     <div id="main-content">
     </div> 
  </div>
</div>
```

Any tips on how to do that?

Comment: What have you tried? Where is your code? SO !== "please give me code" but SO === "I've tried so much, but just can't find it, can yyou help me?"

Comment: I just edit with my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if it's just how you copied it, but your quotation marks for the classes inside of the `.append()` need to either be single quotes or escaped with a backslash ( \ ).

The following worked for me...

#### Html

```
<div id='main-content'></div>
```

#### JS

```
var data = { "locations":
    [
        {"name":"fool1","lat":"41.6504","long":"-0.879137","img":"http://link1.com"},                 
        {"name":"fool2","lat":"41.6049","long":"-0.899137","img":"http://link2.com"}
    ]};

$(function() {
    $.each(data.locations, function(i, l) {
        $('#main-content').append("<div class='thumbnail'>" +
                         "<img src='" + l.img + "' />" +
                         "<div class='number'>" +
                         "<h3>" + "number" + "</h3>" +
                          "</div></div>");
    });
});
```

Also, I don't know if the json object you posted was incomplete but the `f.nombre` that you're trying to put into the class and h3 doesn't exist in the locations object.